# Why would you use a shared volume and also copy the project directory in Docker Compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I'm following [this tutorial](https://testdriven.io/blog/dockerizing-django-with-postgres-gunicorn-and-nginx/) on using Docker Compose to deploy a Django application. It suggests that in my Dockerfile I should have (abbreviated for clarity):

```
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY . .
```

Where the local directory is the Django project root. But also that in my docker-compose.yml (in the parent directory to the project root) I should have the line

```
volumes:
  - ./app/:/usr/src/app/
```

Where ./app/ is the project root, relative to docker-compose.yml. From reading, the `volumes` line in docker-compose should make my host directory ./app/ available in the container at /usr/src/app/. Testing also seems to confirm this.

In that case, what's the point of the `COPY . .` line? In fact beyond the point, why does it not throw an error? It seems to be copying a directory over itself.

Answer (score 0):

Well at beginning in the tutorial, the write just pretends run Dockerfile and docker-composer without entrypoint.sh then is not necessary use: `COPY . .`

But while you continues reading there is a point in Dockerfile that is required have the code of Django inside de Container Docker.
The line that I'm talking about ends in `ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/src/app/entrypoint.sh"]`

So if `COPY . .` is not present, the image building will throw error.

I hope you got me, what I'm say.

Comment: When I remove the COPY instructions, even with the ENTRYPOINT instruction intact, the deployment still works. This makes sense with what I'm reading about volumes, because /usr/src/app should just be a mounting of the host /app directory, shouldn't it?

Comment: You're right, but the order of calls of docker is the main difference. It first will build the image after that it will mount the volume with docker-compose.

Comment: Right, okay. So does the volume instruction in docker-compose just overwrite the container directory /usr/src/project with a mounting of the host folder?

Comment: Yes; it negates the work the Dockerfile does in the directory, and it makes your image dependent on the host system you're running it on.